# will server fail cause client lost their update?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

First let me describe a situation :
A client just update a value(operation succeed), then the server it connect failed, client fail over to another server, but at this time the update has not syn to the new server,then client call getData to get the value it just set. It may see that the value it just set was lost.

I wander how zookeeper deal with this situation.

Comment: The docs https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkGuarantees say _the guarantee is only present with successful return codes_

Comment: I mean the client receive successful return code of the update operation, and then the server failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some resource, I find the answer.
In this paper [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/papers/zookeeper.pdf),it says:

> Responses include the zxid that the response
> is relative to.Even heartbeat messages during intervals
> of no activity include the last zxid seen by the server that
> the client is connected to. If the client connects to a new
> server, that new server ensures that its view of the ZooKeeper data is at least as recent as the view of the client
> by checking the last zxid of the client against its last zxid.
> If the client has a more recent view than the server, the server does not reestablish the session with the client until the server has caught up.

So every update will be assign a zxid shows the current status of zookeeper. When client issue the update operation, the response will have the zxid assigned to this update operation, this zxid will be carried in the next read request. When the server receive the read request, it will compare the zxid with its current zxid, if the zxid from the request is greater than its current zxid, it knows that the client has seen a newer image of the system, so it must sync with leader to catch up with the client.